# span10 into 3 columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html, offset

I need to devide span10 into 3 columns, but am not able to get things to line up. 
Should I add a span12 into the span10 or use offset or??

```
    <div class="container">
   <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span12">

            <div class="span2">Left Menu</div>
            <div class="span10">
               <div class="content>Full Div Content</div

               <div class="spanX">Column 1 Content</div>
               <div class="spanX">Column 2 Content</div>
               <div class="spanX">Column 3 Content</div>

            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: could you provide the CSS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you should use span12 (span9, span6, span3 or new fluid row) inside span10 to divide it in 3 equal columns.

If you would use offset you would only lose horizontal space and it won't be aligned with other containers in the future if you don't add the same offset to all of them. Using span12 inside span10 would give you exactly what you need.